# nebular (setDirection()) how to use it

Tags: direction, nebular

I am using nebular (ngx-admin) want the user can change the direction of the app with button click.
I found in documentation just setDirection() method but without any examples or how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In constructor

```
  constructor(private  directionService: NbLayoutDirectionService) {
  }
```

In Action (Method)

```
this.directionService.setDirection(NbLayoutDirection.LTR);
```